# how can I update a shiny fileInput object?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create an input file dialog. This is straightforward using the `fileInput` function.

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(""),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("file", "Select a file")  
  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

[image]

After uploading it looks like this:
[image]

Now, I want to reset the `inputFile` element to the state it had before uploading. As there is no such function like `updateFileInput`, me being a JS/HTML rookie, I am not able to figure out how I could achieve that. The code output from `fileInput("file", "Select a file")` is the following.

```
<label>Select a file</label>
<input id="file" type="file" accept="text/plain"/>
<div id="file_progress" class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <label></label>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

PS. I do not want to use a reactive `renderUI` here to re-render the file input element. I'd rather want to go the 'update way' (if there is such a thing) ...

Comment: this `shinyjs` approach is very easy compared to the others: https://gist.github.com/bborgesr/07406b30ade8a011e59971835bf6c6f7

Answer (score 9):

As @Julien Navarre pointed out, this boils down to modifying some HTML/CSS. Julien showed how to do that from the client side. What remains to be shown is how to do that from the server side. I.e. the server will invoke a function on the client side that will set back the input handler. You can find a blog post on passing data between server and client using shiny [here](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/).

On the server side the crucial function is `session$sendCustomMessage` which will call a the handler function `resetFileInputHandler` on the client side. The id of the file input object is passed to the handler.

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    input$btn
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetFileInputHandler", "file1") 
  })

})
```

Now, on the client side we need to register a handler function that will be called by the server and perform the necessary changes as outlined by Julien.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

  fileInput('file1', 'Choose File'),
  actionButton("btn", "Trigger server to reset file input"),

  tags$script('
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("resetFileInputHandler", function(x) {      
        var id = "#" + x + "_progress";      # name of progress bar is file1_progress
        var idBar = id + " .bar";  
        $(id).css("visibility", "hidden");   # change visibility
        $(idBar).css("width", "0%");         # reset bar to 0%
    });
  ')
))
```

Pressing the button will now cause the server to invoke the `resetFileInputHandler` on the client side (of course the button is just for demo puposes).

You can find the above code [here](https://gist.github.com/markheckmann/8314905) or run it like this

```
library(shiny)
runGist("8314905")
```

**Caution**

This solution leaves on aspect untouched:The file name shown to the right for the shiny object

```
<input id="file1" type="file" class="shiny-bound-input">
```

is not altered. I guess that would mean digging deeper into it. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

maybe it's too late, but if you still need it,

When the bar appears you can see a new "style" attribute appear :

```
<div id="file1_progress" class="progress progress-striped shiny-file-input-progress" style="visibility: visible;">
```

All you have to do with JS, is to get the element with his id ("file1_progress") and to set the parameter "visibility" of the "style" attribute to "hidden".

I put an example on Gist, you can see it (and the code) by running the following command :

```
shiny::runGist('8306992')
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Below I also set back the filling of the progress bar. ONe problem remains though: How to reset the `<input id="file1" type="file" class="shiny-bound-input">` part? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways of resetting the file input UI (both the progress bar and the displayed name). The first uses JavaScript and the second uses renderUI.

The examples include both a "Clear" button as well as an optional drop-down menu that resets the file input UI when the selection changes.

### Example 1 - using JavaScript

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

    tags$head(
        tags$style(".clearButton {float:right; font-size:12px;}")
    ),

    headerPanel("Reset file input example"),

    sidebarPanel(
        HTML("<button id='clearFile1' class='action-button clearButton'>Clear</button>"),
        fileInput('file1', NULL, width="80%"),

        selectInput('uploadFormat', label = "Select upload format", 
            choices = c(
                "Option 1" = 'f1',
                "Option 2" = 'f2',
                "Option 3" = 'f3'),
            selected = 'f1')
    ),

    mainPanel(
        h4("Summary"),
        verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    ),
    singleton(includeScript("active.js"))
))
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    values <- reactiveValues(
        file1 = NULL
    )

    observe({
        input$clearFile1
        input$uploadFormat
        values$file1 <- NULL
    })

    observe({
        values$file1 <- input$file1
    })

    output$summary <- renderText({
        return(paste("Uploaded file: ", values$file1$name))
    })

})
```

**active.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* clear file button control */
    var fileControl = $("#file1");

    $("#clearFile1").on("click", function () {
        fileControl.replaceWith( fileControl = fileControl.clone( true ) );
        $("#file1_progress").hide();
    });

    $("#uploadFormat").on("change", function () {
        fileControl.replaceWith( fileControl = fileControl.clone( true ) );
        $("#file1_progress").hide();
    });

    /* file input progress bar control */
    $( "#file1" ).change(function() {
      document.getElementById("file1_progress").setAttribute('style', "height:20px; margin-top:5px;");
    });

});
```

### Example 2 - using renderUI

Same as above, but (1) get rid of active.js and the related include statement, (2) in ui.R replace

```
fileInput('file1', NULL, width="80%"),
```

with

```
uiOutput('resettableInput'),
```

and (3) in server.R add:

```
    output$resettableInput <- renderUI({
        input$clearFile1
        input$uploadFormat

        fileInput('file1', NULL, width="80%")
    })
```

Note that one could enclose multiple UI elements in a list() statement here and they would all be re-rendered. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265980/reset-inputs-button-in-shiny-app).

You can find the code for these examples [here](https://gist.github.com/davidarndt/0c2a98a0236f1257fd45) and [here](https://gist.github.com/davidarndt/bc09d77fa92457e094c8), and run them like so:

```
library(shiny)
shiny::runGist('0c2a98a0236f1257fd45')
shiny::runGist('bc09d77fa92457e094c8')
```

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who needs this functionality in the future: you can use the `reset()` function from the `shinyjs` package (since version 0.8) https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs

Comment: Thanks daattali. I tried your code and it resets the `fileInput()`, but I still find files by `input$files`. How to actually reset input$files.

Comment: Any news about reset of files which are at input$files??

Comment: Earlier this week I submitted a PR to shiny that does some work for this. I think it will be in shiny by the end of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best option but below you can find my quick solution which I use.

My system allows to make comments and upload files for each entry in the database.
So when the user uploads and save the fileA for entryX and then pass to entryY... by mistake if the user clicks on save button the same file (fileA) will be also saved for the entryY. To prevent this here my quick solution:

After saving fileA delete the *datapath* and before saving a file check if *datapath* exists;

> > system(paste0("rm ",input$filenote$datapath))
> >
> > file.exists(input$filenote$datapath)

But if the user really wants to save the same file (fileA) for entryX and entryY then he/she has to first upload fileB and then again fileA and then click to save... If you select again fileA after deleting input$filenote$datapath it does not find the fileA....