# 'Reset inputs' button in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to implement a 'Reset inputs' button in my shiny app.

Here is an example with just two inputs where I'm using the update functions to set the values back to the default values:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(

  ui = pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("'Reset inputs' button example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("mynumber", "Enter a number", 20),
      textInput("mytext", "Enter a text", "test"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Summary"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )

  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$summary <- renderText({
      return(paste(input$mytext, input$mynumber))
    })

    observe({
      input$reset_input
      updateNumericInput(session, "mynumber", value = 20)
      updateTextInput(session, "mytext", value = "test")
    })
  }

))
```

What I would like to know is if there is also a function that sets back everything to default? That would be useful in case of multiple inputs.

Additionally, I'm not sure if my use of the observe function in order to detect when the action button was hit is the 'proper way' of handling the action buttons?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There isn't such a function in `shiny`, however, here's a way to accomplish this without having to essentially define your inputs twice. The trick is to use `uiOutput` and wrap the inputs you want to reset in a `div` whose id changes to something new each time the reset button is pressed.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(

  ui = pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("'Reset inputs' button example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput('resetable_input'),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Summary"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )

  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$summary <- renderText({
      return(paste(input$mytext, input$mynumber))
    })

    output$resetable_input <- renderUI({
        times <- input$reset_input
        div(id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],
            numericInput("mynumber", "Enter a number", 20),
            textInput("mytext", "Enter a text", "test"))
    })

  }
))
```

Comment: Many thanks! I have tried the code already on my original app (with 11 instead of 2 inputs) and it works really fine and it is a good thing not to have the inputs twice in the code.

Btw: Do I find somewhere a good help for the html tags? I wasn't aware of the "id" and its usefulness so far.

Comment: @Matthew Plourde, @Insa I don't think div and id are really important here. I replaced `div(id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],` by `list` and it changed nothing.

Comment: this is one of those answers I find myself back at again, and wish I could upvote, but must have done so in the distant past.  So much simpler than writing an observer and having to rewrite everything.

Comment: Gotta say, this was a HUGE time saver...if only I saw it before I wasted my time!

Comment: Just stumbled across this solution before I even knew exactly what I was trying to search for (updateTextInput?). Fantastic solution.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde, I was looking for some help on filtering data and generating crosstables and plots. I would really appreciate any help in let me know how to get this working. I have posted my question and hoping you would be able to suggest some solution. Thank you!! Link to my post is   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187194/shiny-dynamic-filter-variable-selection-and-display-of-variable-values-for-selec

Comment: Great idea indeed! Thanks a million

Comment: I saw this as an answer first, but still have a question: does not it generate a new div() with as many inputs each time it is reset? in terms of memory, I don't think it is the best.

Comment: I believe this answer is outdated. There is a reset() function currently

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/1.1/topics/reset

Answer (score 50):

First of all, your use of the observer is correct, but there is another way that's slightly nicer. Instead of

```
observe({
  input$reset_input
  updateNumericInput(session, "mynumber", value = 20)
  updateTextInput(session, "mytext", value = "test")
})
```

You can change it to

```
observeEvent(input$reset_input, {
  updateNumericInput(session, "mynumber", value = 20)
  updateTextInput(session, "mytext", value = "test")
})
```

Also note that you don't need to explicitly "return" from a renderText function, the last statement will automatically be used.

---

Regarding the main question: Matthew's solution is great, but there's also a way to achieve what you want without having to move all your UI into the server. I think it's better practice to keep your UI in the UI file just because separation of structure and logic is generally a good idea.

Full disclaimer: my solution involves using a package that I wrote. My package [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) has a `reset` function that allows you to reset an input or an HTML section back to its original value. Here is how to tweak your original code to your desired behaviour in a way that will scale to any number of inputs without having to add any code. All I had to do is add a call to `useShinyjs()` in the UI, add an "id" attribute to the form, and call `reset(id)` on the form.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(

  ui = pageWithSidebar(

    headerPanel("'Reset inputs' button example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
      id = "side-panel",
      numericInput("mynumber", "Enter a number", 20),
      textInput("mytext", "Enter a text", "test"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h4("Summary"),
      verbatimTextOutput("summary")
    )

  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$summary <- renderText({
      return(paste(input$mytext, input$mynumber))
    })

    observeEvent(input$reset_input, {
      shinyjs::reset("side-panel")
    })
  }

))
```

Comment: I was looking for some help on filtering data and generating crosstables and plots. I would really appreciate any help in let me know how to get this working. I have posted my question and hoping you would be able to suggest some solution. Thank you!! Link to my post is   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187194/shiny-dynamic-filter-variable-selection-and-display-of-variable-values-for-selec

Comment: Thank you Dean, do you think it's possible to add yours function directly in shiny or shinydashboards packages ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko do you mean moving the reset function into shiny? I don't think that's going to happen. You can ask rstudio about it, if they want to. But shinyjs has lots of other similarly useful functions so I think it makes sense to keep them packages together

Comment: @DeanAttali If you're using `flexdashboard` what argument do your refer to within `shinyjs::reset()` to indicate you want to reset the sidebar panel? The issue is that in `flexdashboard` you don't explicitly provide an `id` name to the sidebar panel.

Comment: Never mind - I realize you can refer to the inputs themselves, which works just as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here is yet another option that works for either static or dynamic inputs, and doesn't involve re-rendering inputs entirely.

It uses:

[`reactiveValuesToList`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/reactiveValuesToList.html) to get all initial input values, and (optionally) any dynamic input values that get initialized afterward.

[`session$sendInputMessage`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/session.html) to update values for generic inputs. The `updateXyzInput` functions call this under the hood like `session$sendInputMessage(inputId, list(value = x, ...)`.

Every Shiny input uses `value` for its input message, and almost all will update with their input value as-is. Only a two inputs I've found need special casing - `checkboxGroupInput` to not send `NULL` when nothing is checked, and `dateRangeInput` to convert its `c(start, end)` to a `list(start = start, end = end)`.

It may not be a good idea to blindly reset ALL inputs (even tabs will be reset), but this can easily be adapted to reset a filtered set of inputs.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("'Reset inputs' button example"),

  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("mynumber", "Enter a number", 20),
    textInput("mytext", "Enter text", "test"),
    textAreaInput("mytextarea", "Enter text", "test"),
    passwordInput("mypassword", "Enter a password", "password"),
    checkboxInput("mycheckbox", "Check"),
    checkboxGroupInput("mycheckboxgroup", "Choose a number", choices = c(1, 2, 3)),
    radioButtons("myradio", "Select a number", c(1, 2, 3)),
    sliderInput("myslider", "Select a number", 1, 5, c(1,2)),
    uiOutput("myselUI"),
    uiOutput("mydateUI"),
    tags$hr(),
    actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4("Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("summary")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  initialInputs <- isolate(reactiveValuesToList(input))

  observe({
    # OPTIONAL - save initial values of dynamic inputs
    inputValues <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    initialInputs <<- utils::modifyList(inputValues, initialInputs)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset_input, {
    for (id in names(initialInputs)) {
      value <- initialInputs[[id]]
      # For empty checkboxGroupInputs
      if (is.null(value)) value <- ""
      session$sendInputMessage(id, list(value = value))
    }
  })

  output$myselUI <- renderUI({
    selectInput("mysel", "Select a number", c(1, 2, 3))
  })

  output$mydateUI <- renderUI({
    dateInput("mydate", "Enter a date")
  })

  output$summary <- renderText({
    return(paste(input$mytext, input$mynumber))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a reset button by assigning `NULL` to your reactive values object.

See this RStudio Shiny article on **Using Action Buttons**: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html. Specifically, read the sections titled *Pattern 4 - Reset buttons* and *Pattern 5 - Reset on tab change*. Examples (including code) are provided in the article.

The article provides solutions that don't require additional packages if that's a concern.