# Shiny: Reset sidebar controls to default values

Tags: r, shiny, reset, reactive-programming

I have a shiny App and would like to add a "Reset" button to clear all inputs. This is particularly useful if one has several inputs and does not want to reset each manually.

I tried the idea given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265980/reset-inputs-button-in-shiny-app). It somewhat works in a buggy way but for some reason it prints the names of the variables above the reset button, ie. "categ_1", "date", "categ_2". Also, I don't know how to combine update & uiOutput in the below line:

```
 output$resetable_input <- renderUI({
         times <- input$reset_input
         div(
           id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],
           #                updateuiOutput(session,"firm"),
           updateSelectInput(session,"categ_1",
                             choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_1)))),
           updateSelectInput(session,"date", 
                             choices = c("All","Last 28 Days","Last Quarter")),
           updateSelectInput(session,"categ_2",
                             choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_2))))
         )
       })
```

Has anyone found an easy way to do this?

Many Thanks in advance!

1. Create sample data

   ```
     set.seed(1)
     df <- data.frame(FIRM=rep(LETTERS[1:7],each=10), CATEG_1=rbinom(70,4,0.9),CATEG_2=rbinom(70,1,0.2),date=as.Date("2014-01-01")+1:10,y1=sample(1:100,70))
   ```
2. shiny App

   ```
    library(shiny)
    library(rCharts)
    library(doBy)
    library(plyr)

     shinyApp(ui = 
      shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

        # Application title
        headerPanel("Example"),

        sidebarPanel(
          uiOutput("firm"),
          #  selectInput("firm", "Filter by firm:", 
          #   choices = unique(as.character(df))),
          selectInput("categ_1", "Filter by Category 1:",
                      choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_1)))),
          selectInput("date", "Filter by Date:", 
                      choices = c("All","Last 28 Days","Last Quarter")),
          selectInput("categ_2", "Filter by Category 2:", 
                      choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_2)))),
          uiOutput('resetable_input'),
          actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")         
        ), #sidebarPanel

        mainPanel(
          h4("Example plot",style = "color:grey"),
          showOutput("plot", "nvd3")
        ) # mainPanel
      ) #sidebarLayout
      ) #shinyU
    , 
    server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

      subset_data <- reactive({df <- filter_data(df,input$firm,
                                                 input$date,
                                                 input$categ_1,
                                                 input$categ_2)
                               shiny::validate(need(!is.null(df),"No data to display"))
                               return(df)})

      output$firm <- renderUI({
        input$date
        input$categ_1
        input$categ_2
        selectInput("firm", "Filter by Firm:",
                    choices = c("All",as.character(unique(isolate(subset_data()$FIRM)))))
      })

         output$resetable_input <- renderUI({
        times <- input$reset_input
        div(
          id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],
          #                updateuiOutput(session,"firm"),
          updateSelectInput(session,"categ_1",
                            choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_1)))),
          updateSelectInput(session,"date", 
                            choices = c("All","Last 28 Days","Last Quarter")),
          updateSelectInput(session,"categ_2", 
                            choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_2))))
        )
      })



      output$plot<-renderChart2({ build_plot(subset_data()) })

      ##############
      #below are the functions used in the code
      ##############

      # function for date subsetting 

      filter_date<-function(df,dateRange="All"){
        filt <- df
        td <- max(as.Date(filt$date))
        if (dateRange=='Last 28 Days'){filt <-filt[filt$date>=(td-28),]}
        if (dateRange=='Last Quarter'){filt <-filt[filt$date>=(td-84),]}
        return(filt)
      }  # filter by date

      # function for data subsetting 

      filter_data<-function(df,firm=NULL,dateRange="All",categ_1=NULL,categ_2=NULL)
      { 
        filt<-filter_date(df,dateRange)

        if (!is.null(firm)) {
          if(firm!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$FIRM==firm,]}
        }
        if (!is.null(categ_1)){
          if (categ_1!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$CATEG_1==categ_1,]}
        } 
        if (!is.null(categ_2)) {
          if (categ_2!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$CATEG_2==categ_2,]} 
        }

        if(nrow(filt)==0) {filt <- NULL}
        return(filt)
      } # prepare data to be plotted

      # function to create plot

      build_plot <- function(df) {
        plotData<-df
        # If 1 firms selected, time series is shown  
        if (length(as.character(unique(plotData$FIRM)))==1) {

          tabledta<-summaryBy(y1~FIRM+date,data=plotData,FUN=sum,keep.names=TRUE) 

          filler = expand.grid(FIRM=as.character(unique(df$FIRM)),
                               date=seq(min(tabledta$date),max(tabledta$date),by='1 day'))
          df = merge(filler,
                     tabledta,
                     by=c('date','FIRM'),
                     all.x=T)
          df[is.na(df)]=0
          p <- nPlot(y1 ~ date, group = 'FIRM', data = df, type = 'lineChart')
          p$chart(margin=list(left=150))
          p$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE)
          p$xAxis(tickFormat ="#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));}!#")
          p
        }
        # If "All" firms are selected, barchart of Top 5 is shown
        else{
          SummaryTab<-aggregate(y1~FIRM,data=plotData,FUN=sum)
          SummaryTab$rank=rank(SummaryTab$y1)
          SummaryTab$rank[SummaryTab$rank>5]<-6

          if (length(SummaryTab$rank)>5) {
            #Top 5 firms in terms of y1 are shown
            top5<-SummaryTab[SummaryTab$rank<=5,]
            # other firms are collapsed, shown as 1 entry

            others<-aggregate(y1~rank,data=SummaryTab,FUN=sum)  
            others<-others[others$rank==6,]
            others$FIRM<-"Others"

            # Create the summarytable to be plotted
            plotData=rbind(top5,others)}

          tabledta<-summaryBy(y1~FIRM,data=plotData,FUN=sum,keep.names=TRUE) 
          tabledta<-arrange(tabledta,y1) 
          #   if(is.null(tabledta)) {print("Input is an empty string")}

          p <- nPlot(y1 ~ FIRM,data = tabledta, type = 'multiBarHorizontalChart')    
          p$chart(margin=list(left=150))
          p$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE)
          p
        }

      }
    }) #shinyServer
     )
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `selectInput` sections in the `ui.R` file are not needed any longer, because you are going to replace them by the dynamically generated `selectInput`.
2. There should not be `UpdateSelectInput` in the `output$resetable_input` expression -- it should be just the same `selectInput` that you used to have in ui.R.
3. The `div` and `id` things are useless (to the best of my knowledge) in the `output$resetable_input` expression, you can safely replace them by `list()`:

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   df <- data.frame(FIRM=rep(LETTERS[1:7],each=10), CATEG_1=rbinom(70,4,0.9),CATEG_2=rbinom(70,1,0.2),date=as.Date("2014-01-01")+1:10,y1=sample(1:100,70))

    library(shiny)
    library(rCharts)
    library(doBy)
    library(plyr)

     shinyApp(ui = 
      shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

        # Application title
        headerPanel("Example"),

        sidebarPanel(
          uiOutput("firm"),
          #  selectInput("firm", "Filter by firm:", 
          #   choices = unique(as.character(df))),
          #selectInput("categ_1", "Filter by Category 1:",
                      #choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_1)))),
          #selectInput("date", "Filter by Date:", 
                      #choices = c("All","Last 28 Days","Last Quarter")),
          #selectInput("categ_2", "Filter by Category 2:", 
                      #choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_2)))),
          uiOutput('resetable_input'),
          actionButton("reset_input", "Reset inputs")         
        ), #sidebarPanel

        mainPanel(
          h4("Example plot",style = "color:grey"),
          showOutput("plot", "nvd3")
        ) # mainPanel
      ) #sidebarLayout
      ) #shinyU
    , 
    server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  

      subset_data <- reactive({df <- filter_data(df,input$firm,
                                                 input$date,
                                                 input$categ_1,
                                                 input$categ_2)
                               shiny::validate(need(!is.null(df),"No data to display"))
                               return(df)})

      output$firm <- renderUI({
        input$date
        input$categ_1
        input$categ_2
        selectInput("firm", "Filter by Firm:",
                    choices = c("All",as.character(unique(isolate(subset_data()$FIRM)))))
      })

         output$resetable_input <- renderUI({
        times <- input$reset_input
        div(
          id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],
          selectInput("categ_1", "Filter by Category 1:",
                      choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_1)))),
          selectInput("date", "Filter by Date:", 
                      choices = c("All","Last 28 Days","Last Quarter")),
          selectInput("categ_2", "Filter by Category 2:", 
                      choices = c("All",unique(as.character(df$CATEG_2))))
        )
      })



      output$plot<-renderChart2({ build_plot(subset_data()) })

      ##############
      #below are the functions used in the code
      ##############

      # function for date subsetting 

      filter_date<-function(df,dateRange="All"){
        filt <- df
        td <- max(as.Date(filt$date))
        if (dateRange=='Last 28 Days'){filt <-filt[filt$date>=(td-28),]}
        if (dateRange=='Last Quarter'){filt <-filt[filt$date>=(td-84),]}
        return(filt)
      }  # filter by date

      # function for data subsetting 

      filter_data<-function(df,firm=NULL,dateRange="All",categ_1=NULL,categ_2=NULL)
      { 
        filt<-filter_date(df,dateRange)

        if (!is.null(firm)) {
          if(firm!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$FIRM==firm,]}
        }
        if (!is.null(categ_1)){
          if (categ_1!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$CATEG_1==categ_1,]}
        } 
        if (!is.null(categ_2)) {
          if (categ_2!='All') {filt <- filt[filt$CATEG_2==categ_2,]} 
        }

        if(nrow(filt)==0) {filt <- NULL}
        return(filt)
      } # prepare data to be plotted

      # function to create plot

      build_plot <- function(df) {
        plotData<-df
        # If 1 firms selected, time series is shown  
        if (length(as.character(unique(plotData$FIRM)))==1) {

          tabledta<-summaryBy(y1~FIRM+date,data=plotData,FUN=sum,keep.names=TRUE) 

          filler = expand.grid(FIRM=as.character(unique(df$FIRM)),
                               date=seq(min(tabledta$date),max(tabledta$date),by='1 day'))
          df = merge(filler,
                     tabledta,
                     by=c('date','FIRM'),
                     all.x=T)
          df[is.na(df)]=0
          p <- nPlot(y1 ~ date, group = 'FIRM', data = df, type = 'lineChart')
          p$chart(margin=list(left=150))
          p$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE)
          p$xAxis(tickFormat ="#!function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));}!#")
          p
        }
        # If "All" firms are selected, barchart of Top 5 is shown
        else{
          SummaryTab<-aggregate(y1~FIRM,data=plotData,FUN=sum)
          SummaryTab$rank=rank(SummaryTab$y1)
          SummaryTab$rank[SummaryTab$rank>5]<-6

          if (length(SummaryTab$rank)>5) {
            #Top 5 firms in terms of y1 are shown
            top5<-SummaryTab[SummaryTab$rank<=5,]
            # other firms are collapsed, shown as 1 entry

            others<-aggregate(y1~rank,data=SummaryTab,FUN=sum)  
            others<-others[others$rank==6,]
            others$FIRM<-"Others"

            # Create the summarytable to be plotted
            plotData=rbind(top5,others)}

          tabledta<-summaryBy(y1~FIRM,data=plotData,FUN=sum,keep.names=TRUE) 
          tabledta<-arrange(tabledta,y1) 
          #   if(is.null(tabledta)) {print("Input is an empty string")}

          p <- nPlot(y1 ~ FIRM,data = tabledta, type = 'multiBarHorizontalChart')    
          p$chart(margin=list(left=150))
          p$yAxis(showMaxMin = FALSE)
          p
        }

      }
    }) #shinyServer
     )
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much! I did try it with list but it was not resettable anymore then.

Comment: Did you remove `id=letters[(times %% length(letters)) + 1],` when you replaced `div()` by `list()`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I had removed the "times <- input$reset_input" as well which is needed. I see what you mean now. Thank you!