# Reset Shiny widgets with Shinyjs and googlesheets

Tags: shiny, shinyjs, r-googlesheets

My app takes user input and stores it in google sheets.I'd like to have an action button that resets all sidebar-panel ui inputs when button is clicked. I gave it a try with shinyjs [just like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265980/reset-inputs-button-in-shiny-app) but I get the grey screen every time I press the button. I also tried resetting each widget individually using 3 different Shinyjs observeEvent reset's. My question is if the "Run JS code" for capturing location is interfering with resetting the side-panel.

> ```
>      library(shiny)
>      library(googlesheets)
>      library(dplyr)
>      library(shinyjs)
> ```

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(""),

    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    id = "side-panel",
    selectInput("names",
              "Name:",c(" ","Steve","Bob","Sally"),selected=" "),
    radioButtons("radio", "",
               c("Checking In" = "In","Heading Out" = "Out"),                 

  selected="NULL"),
  textInput("destination","Notes"),
  actionButton("capture", "Share Location"),
  tags$hr(),
  actionButton("submit","Submit")  
),

mainPanel(
  textOutput("distPlot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("lat"),
  verbatimTextOutput("long"),
  tableOutput("Table")
  #verbatimTextOutput("geolocation")
     )
     )
     )
     )
```

## Server

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

    output$distPlot <- renderText({  

x= if(input$names=="Steve") {
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$names, anchor = "A2"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$destination, anchor = "B2"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$radio, anchor = "C2"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=format(Sys.time(), "%a %D %X"), anchor = "D2"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$lat, anchor = "E2"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$long, anchor = "F2"))
  } else if (input$names=="Bob"){
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$names, anchor = "A3"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$destination, anchor = "B3"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$radio, anchor = "C3"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=format(Sys.time(), "%a %D %X"), anchor = "D3"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$lat, anchor = "E3"))
  print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$long, anchor = "F3"))
  } else if (input$names=="Sally"){
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$names, anchor = "A4"))
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$destination, anchor = "B4"))
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$radio, anchor = "C4"))
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=format(Sys.time(), "%a %D %X"), anchor = "D4"))
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$lat, anchor = "E4"))
    print(gs_edit_cells(safety, ws = "Sheet1",input=input$long, anchor = "F4"))
   } else {
  print()
      }

      })  

          observeEvent(input$submit, {
          shinyjs::reset("side-panel")

          })



        observeEvent(input$capture, {
        # Run JS code to get location
        runjs('
       $(document).ready(function () {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

      function onError (err) {
      Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation",false);
      }

      function onSuccess (position) {
      setTimeout(function () {
      var coords = position.coords;
      console.log(coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude);
      Shiny.onInputChange("geolocation", true);
      Shiny.onInputChange("lat", coords.latitude);
      Shiny.onInputChange("long", coords.longitude);
      }, 1100)
      }
      });
      ')
       })


    output$lat <- renderPrint({
    input$lat
   })

  output$long <- renderPrint({
  input$long
  })

  })
```

Comment: You have a typo : `selected=NULL`

Comment: selected ="NULL" for selectInput defaults to the first item in the list. I wanted it blank so " " is actually one of the names in my list. I tried it regardless, same issue occurs if I change it to selected to "NULL"

Comment: just removing the double quotes makes your code work...