# Setting a "Reset Values" button on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

I have put together a Shiny app that reactively creates lists while simultaneously removing those selections from the list you're selecting from. I'm trying to put together a feature where you click a reset button and it does the following:

1.) Deselects all input options

2.) Sets the Age Range to 18 - 104 (so it captures all values)

3.) Moves the other two sliders to zero

I'm trying to use the `shinyjs::reset` function, but it doesn't appear to be working. Take a look:

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gooponyagrinch/sample_data/master/datasheet.csv')

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(id = "myapp",
  fluidRow(
    column("",
           width = 10, offset = 1,
           tags$h3("Select Area"),
           panel(
             sliderInput("current", "Current Score",
                         min = 0, max = 100, value = 20),
             sliderInput("projected", "Projected Score",
                         min = 0, max = 100, value = 20),
             sliderInput("age", "Age",
                         min = 18, max = max(df$age), value = c(18,24)),
             checkboxGroupInput("ethnicity",label = "Ethnicity", 
                                choices = list("Caucasian"="Caucasian",
                                               "African-American"="African-American",
                                               "Hispanic"="Hispanic",
                                               "Other"="Other")),
             checkboxInput('previous', label = "Previous Sale"),
             checkboxInput('warm', label = "Warm Lead"),
             actionButton("button", "Add to List"),
             actionButton("reset", "Reset form")), 
           textOutput("counter"),
           tags$h2("Data to filter"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
           tags$h2("IDs added to list"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("addedToList")
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filterData = reactiveVal(df %>% mutate(key = 1:nrow(df)))
  addedToList = reactiveVal(data.frame())

  filtered_df <- reactive({

    res <- filterData() %>% filter(current_grade >= input$current)
    res <- res %>% filter(projected_grade >= input$projected)
    res <- res %>% filter(age >= input$age[1] & age <= input$age[2])
    res <- res %>% filter(ethnicity %in% input$ethnicity | is.null(input$ethnicity))

    if(input$previous == TRUE)
      res <- res %>% filter(previous_sale == 1)

    if(input$warm == TRUE)
      res <- res %>% filter(warm_lead == 1)

    res

  })

  output$counter <- renderText({
    res <- filtered_df() %>% select(customer_id) %>% n_distinct()
    res
  })


  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    res <- filtered_df() %>% distinct(customer_id)
    res

  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {

    addedToList(rbind(addedToList(), 
                      filterData() %>% filter(key %in% filtered_df()$key) %>% 
                        select(customer_id) %>% distinct() ))

    filterData(filterData() %>% filter(!key %in% filtered_df()$key))

  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    shinyjs::reset("myapp")
  })

  output$addedToList <- renderDataTable({
    addedToList()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is ensure that your application is listening for a call to "ShinyJS" in your application. In the UI, add the useShinyJS() call!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyJS()
  div(id = "myapp",
  fluidRow(...)
)
```

I also should note this looks like a repeat of this question. ['Reset inputs' button in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265980/reset-inputs-button-in-shiny-app?rq=1)