# Shiny DT datatable selectInput with reactive data

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I recently asked a similar question ([Shiny DT datatable input reactivity after table is reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607777/shiny-dt-datatable-input-reactivity-after-table-is-reloaded)). My issue was getting a selectInput in a DT datatable to work correctly after the table is reloaded. The solution worked, which was to use javascript to unbind before reloading the table. However, that example used a static dataframe. When the input data in the datatable are reactive, it doesn't work. In the example below, when the user clicks "Update data" the first time to load data, the selectInput works correctly and `input$id1` responds to the user selection. However, when the user clicks "Update data" again to update the reactive data, the `input$id` no longer responds to the user selection. I've seen two potential approaches to address the issue. One is using `dataTableProxy()` and `replaceData()`, and the other is renaming the selectInput ids each time the reactive data are updated. I was wondering if I can avoid those two approaches and get this example working with minimal changes.

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
      HTML(
        "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
            var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
            if($table.length > 0){
              Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
            }
          })")
    )),
    actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update data"),
    uiOutput("resettable_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(
      times = 1, 
      mydata = NULL
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "mytable")
      rv$times <- rv$times + 1
      rv$mydata <- data.frame(
        Col1 = as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = "id1",
          label = NULL,
          choices = paste0(letters, input$update),
          selected = paste0(letters, input$update)[1],
        ))
      )
    })
    
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(rv$mydata)
      DT::datatable(
        data = rv$mydata,
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          preDrawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
          drawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
        )
      )
    }, server = F)
    
    output$resettable_table <- renderUI({
      req(rv$times)
      div(
        id = paste0("mydiv", rv$times),
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
      )
    })
    
    observe({
      if(is.null(input$id1)) {
        print("input$id1 is NULL")
      } else {
        print(paste(c("input$id1:", input$id1)))
      }
    })
    
  }
)
```

**Update**

Thanks to @StephaneLaurent for pointing out that the reactive counter keeping track of the number of times the data were reloaded was causing the issue. It wasn't actually necessary to put the DT datatable inside a div with an id that updated each time. Here is working code:

```
require(shiny)
require(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
      HTML(
        "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('unbindDT', function(id) {
            var $table = $('#'+id).find('table');
            if($table.length > 0){
              Shiny.unbindAll($table.DataTable().table().node());
            }
          })")
    )),
    actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update data"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(mydata = NULL)
    
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      session$sendCustomMessage("unbindDT", "mytable")
      rv$mydata <- data.frame(
        Col1 = as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = "id1",
          label = NULL,
          choices = paste0(letters, input$update),
          selected = paste0(letters, input$update)[1],
        ))
      )
    })
    
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(rv$mydata)
      DT::datatable(
        data = rv$mydata,
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          preDrawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'),
          drawCallback = JS('function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
        )
      )
    }, server = F)
    
    observe({
      if(is.null(input$id1)) {
        print("input$id1 is NULL")
      } else {
        print(paste(c("input$id1:", input$id1)))
      }
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Hmm... the problem is caused by `rv$times` in the `renderUI`. If you remove it (two occurences), this works.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent that does work, much simpler than the two alternatives! Will post updated code shortly. Thank you.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent feel free to copy the working code into an answer if you'd like and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the presence of `rv$times` in the `renderUI`. The simplest way to make this app work is to get rid of this `renderUI`.

However, for fun, and in order to understand what happens, I did the app below which works with the `renderUI` and which shows what happens. The key point was to remove the `id1` element when the table is consecutively rendered two times, before the second rendering. To do so, I use a JavaScript counter `i`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
      HTML("var i = 1;")
    )),
    actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Update data"),
    uiOutput("resettable_table")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(
      times = 1, 
      mydata = NULL
    )
    
    observeEvent(input$update, {
      rv$times <- rv$times + 1
      rv$mydata <- data.frame(
        Col1 = as.character(selectInput(
          inputId = "id1",
          label = NULL,
          choices = paste0(letters, input$update),
          selected = paste0(letters, input$update)[1],
        ))
      )
    })
    
    output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(rv$mydata)
      DT::datatable(
        data = rv$mydata,
        escape = F,
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          initComplete = JS('function(settings) { alert("initComplete - incrementing i"); i++; alert("i = " + i)}'),
          preDrawCallback = JS('function() { alert("preDrawCallback triggered - unbinding"); Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
          drawCallback = JS('function() { alert("drawCallback triggered - i = " + i); if(i===2) {alert("removing id1 and resetting i to 0"); $("#id1").remove(); i=0;} Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}')
        )
      ) 
    }, server = F)
    
    output$resettable_table <- renderUI({
      div(
        id = paste0("mydiv", rv$times),
        tags$p(paste0("mydiv", rv$times)),
        DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
      )
    })
    
    observe({
      if(is.null(input$id1)) {
        print("input$id1 is NULL")
      } else {
        print(paste(c("input$id1:", input$id1)))
      }
    })
    
  }
)
```