# How to bind select inputs in shiny datatable with shiny 1.8.0

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app involving a datatable where each row contains a select input. A subsequent action button executes various functionality based on how the user populated each row's input. This was based on [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/update-dt-table-dropdowns-with-reactive-data-in-shiny/96100/2) post. This has ceased working with an update to shiny 1.8.0, with the inputs no longer found. I think this is because of changes to the bindings but I can't figure out how to get this working again. I tried using drawCallback and preDrawCallback as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889462/shiny-dt-datatable-with-selectinputs-how-to-retain-selections-after-switching) with no success.

I've made a simplied example below. Pressing the check button should print the currently selected value of the "Cat" dropdown in the console but instead it just returns NULL because (I think) input$C is not correctly bound back to shiny. Any suggestions how I do this? Thanks

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tabledata <- data.frame(name = c('Cat', 'Dog', 'Mouse'),
                        code = c('C','D','M'),
                        status = NA)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("demo"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel('blank'),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('mytab'),
      
      actionButton(inputId = 'check', label = 'Check')
    )
  )
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  #loop over animals to make the dropdowns
  for (i in 1:nrow(tabledata)) {
    tabledata$status[i] <- as.character(selectInput(inputId = paste(tabledata$code[i]),
                                                    label = "",
                                                    choices = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
                                                    selected = "Y")
    )
  }
  
  #the callback is essential to capture the inputs in each row
  output$mytab = DT::renderDataTable(
    tabledata, 
    escape = FALSE, 
    selection = 'none', 
    server = FALSE, 
    rownames= FALSE,
    options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());"
                  )

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$check,{
    print(input$C)
  })
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why adding `selectize = FALSE` to the selections solves this, but it does. Also you don't need to unbind; you can just use `Shiny.bindAll()`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tabledata <- data.frame(
  name = c("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"),
  code = c("C", "D", "M"),
  status = NA
)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("demo"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("blank"),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("mytab"),
      actionButton(inputId = "check", label = "Check")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # loop over animals to make the dropdowns
  for (i in 1:nrow(tabledata)) {
    tabledata$status[i] <- as.character(selectInput(
      inputId = paste(tabledata$code[i]),
      label = "",
      choices = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
      selected = "Y",
      selectize = FALSE
    ))
  }

  # the callback is essential to capture the inputs in each row
  output$mytab <- DT::renderDataTable(
    tabledata,
    escape = FALSE,
    selection = "none",
    server = FALSE,
    rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(dom = "t", paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
        var $this = $(this.node());
        $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
        $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
      });
      Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
      Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
  )

  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$check, {
    print(input$C)
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```