# Unload datafile after it has been uploaded in Shiny

Tags: shiny

fileInput allows users to upload their data in Shiny. Is there any way to unload the data while the data was already uploaded?

Comment: What do you mean by "unloading"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I update a shiny fileInput object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352086/how-can-i-update-a-shiny-fileinput-object)