# How to reset a value of fileInput in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

There are already similar posts on this matter (ex. [how can I update a shiny fileInput object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352086/how-can-i-update-a-shiny-fileinput-object)), but I still cannot figure out how one may force Shiny to forget a value of `input$file` after the `fileInput` widget is used.

The problem becomes nagging when one wants to trigger the upload of file with `actionButton` (called `"Submit"` in my case) and then reset its value with another `actionButton` (`"Reset"` here). **When the "Submit" button is clicked again, it becomes evident that the input$file value is still there.**

I tried to use some recommended solutions: `shinyjs` package and refreshing `fileInput` module with `renderUI`/`uiOutput` - but still with no result.

Here is my code:

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

values <- reactiveValues(
 file = NULL
)

observeEvent(input$submit, {
 values$file <- input$file1
})

observeEvent(input$reset, {
 values$file <- NULL
 output$resettableInput <- renderUI({
  fileInput('file1', label = NULL)
 })
}, ignoreNULL = F)

output$summary <- renderText({
 return(paste('Uploaded file:', values$file$name))
})
})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

 headerPanel('Reset / Submit file input example'),

 sidebarPanel(

  uiOutput('resettableInput'),

  fluidRow(
          column(4,
                 actionButton('reset', 'Reset All')
          ),
          column(4,
                 actionButton('submit', 'Submit')
          )
  )
 ),

 mainPanel(
  h4('Summary'),
  verbatimTextOutput('summary')
 )
))
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 15):

`input$file1` is cached by Shiny so will not change before next upload.

Since you want a file name variable which map to `input$file1$name` in most time but reset to `NULL` when reset button is clicked, you need to create another layer and maintain this relationship.

- You can create a variable `upload_state`, set it to `uploaded` with file upload event, and `reset` with reset button.
- use a reactive expression which will take `input$file1$name` or `NULL` according to `upload_state` value.

There is no need for the `submit` button.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  headerPanel("Reset / Submit file input example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', label = NULL),
    fluidRow(
      column(4,
             actionButton('reset', 'Reset Input')
      ))
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4("Summary"),
    verbatimTextOutput("summary")
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(
    upload_state = NULL
  )

  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    values$upload_state <- 'uploaded'
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    values$upload_state <- 'reset'
  })

  file_input <- reactive({
    if (is.null(values$upload_state)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if (values$upload_state == 'uploaded') {
      return(input$file1)
    } else if (values$upload_state == 'reset') {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  output$summary <- renderText({
    return(paste("Uploaded file:", file_input()$name))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Since upload of single file is only small part of whole project (the program reads data in various ways including several `fileInputs`), the `Submit` button is a key element. Moreover, I as far as I can see your "second layer" plays the same role as my `values$file` reactive value. Anyway, thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Pawel First important difference is to use the reactive expression properly, which solved your problem. Second I choose a different name from `file` intentionally, since you have no control on `input$file1` and you want this variable to be different. Besides, if my answer solved your problem, you can "accept" it as answer and give a upvote. This is how asking question in SO works. Otherwise it looks like you don't think this solved your problem and is still waiting for new answer.

Comment: @dracodocTo be more clear: in my real application I have as many as 8 fileInput widgets. I need to let a user to show and hide them, and to change loaded files flexibly. To make communication efficient I need Submit button. It is possible that user firstly loads for example three files, but then decides to cancel one of them and stay with remaining two. The problem is that the third would be still in cache, thus it would be also 'submited'. So, even though I find your code more elegant than mine, I cannot accept it as proper answer. I would give an upvote, but my reputation is too weak.

Comment: Then you need to state the full picture in the question. The sumbit button still doesn't make sense because the file is already uploaded. To select files to be used in next step, you can use various methods to select already uploaded files, like a check box for each file uploader, or a table showing all uploaded files, select row to remove the one user don't want.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post, but you can reset the input by rebuilding it from scratch in the server.

In ui.R you can put:

```
...
uiOutput('file1_ui') ## instead of fileInput('file1', label = NULL)
...
```

And in server.R add this:

```
...
output$file1_ui <- renderUI({
  input$reset ## Create a dependency with the reset button
  fileInput('file1', label = NULL)
})
...
```

Comment: I agree that this is the most general and dependable way for any shiny question like "how do I reset XXX?"

Comment: Note that this clears the input form, but doesn't change the value of `input$file1` like above, so things that depend on the file that was uploaded aren't invalidated and re-rendered.